# How can I "enable" scrolling up and down in a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiviewcontroller

Ok, I have a navigation Controller that manages a drilldown tableview, when it reaches to the end it show a list of products, when you choose a product it will show a detail view (UiViewController).

What I want to know is how to "Enable" scrolling up and down in that detail view so i can show full information about the product to the user.

Thanks

Comment: Generally with a UIScrollView, thought there are other approaches if the scrolling is program-controlled vs using finger drags.

Comment: Hi @Zulu22 rather than edit your solution into your question, you should answer your own question and mark it as accepted. Really helps the site out and keeps things organized! Thanks and good first question!

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that. I will definitely do that for now on.

Comment: @Zulu22 Thank you for sharing knowledge here but please! post the solution in answer block so everyone come to know this question is solved, hope you got me.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Ok, done that. but it says that i can´t mark my answer until tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer. If you are using Storyboards (like myself) you have to go to the attributes inspector of the UiViewController and change the size parameter to freeform, then select the UIView of the UIViewController and in the size inspector choose whatever width or height you want and finally grab the Scroll View from the object library and insert it.

Comment: This is AWESOME! This also helps when creating tableviews or collection views with large cell templates! Just resize the UIViewController! :-D

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `UIScrollView` to the view controller's view, and set its `contentSize`.